# How to set the Foursquare OAuth in RESTClient

Tags: api, rest, wso2, foursquare

I am trying to use the Foursquare REST APIs in RESTClient(firefox). 
I run a sample like, 
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/{USER_ID}?v={USER_ID}

Also I set the Authorization like,
Authorization: Bearer

But I found the error as,

```
code: 400,
errorType: invalid_auth
```

Please anyone give an idea how to set the Authorization Header for the Foursquare.
I have done all the things which is mentioned on auth overview of developerfoursquare page and got the access token.

- Amaaniy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use foursquare you need to authenticate first

```
 https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate
?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
```

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

once you get token back you can use any other endpoint

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3?oauth_token=XXX&v=YYYYMMDD.